# Map of maps - how sort inner map with lambda?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, collections, alphabetical-sort

I have a map like this:

> Map<String,Map<String,String>>

And I need to sort the second map, so I try something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> response = new ArrayList<>();

response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB2"); add("1"); }});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB125"); add("3");}});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE1"); add("COB55"); add("4");}});
response.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("STATE2"); add("UI5"); add("100");}});

Supplier<TreeMap<String, String>> typeMap = () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());

Object result = response.stream().collect(groupingBy((ArrayList p) -> p.get(0).toString(), Collectors.toMap(
(ArrayList p) -> p.get(1).toString(),
(ArrayList p) -> p.get(2).toString(), (u, v) -> v,typeMap)));

Map<String, Map<String, String>> finalMap = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) result;
```

`finalMap` = STATE1 => {**COB125**=3, **COB2**=1, **COB55**=4}, STATE2 => {UI5=100}

I need different sort type, I tried with the `Comparator.naturalOrder()`
But I need:

`expectedMap`  STATE1 => {**COB2**=3, **COB55**=1, **COB125**=4}, STATE2 => {*UI5*=100}

Comment: What objects are in `response`? What is an `ActionsList`? What is `mainList`?  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. Consider reducing the code to a [mcve] that others can actually execute... you'll probably figure out the problem in the process of doing that (a very useful exercise when confronting a difficult problem).

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for the recommendation. question has been edited